# Highlight text in textbox without modifying the markup

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, highlighting

I was wondering if it were possible to write an extension for a browser which would change the color of text, or otherwise transform it (underline, bold, etc) without modifying the markup.

As an example:

**HTML**

```
<p>Extensions use JS, and have to modify the DOM<p>
```

**Default Rendering**

Extensions use JS, and have to modify the DOM

**Desired Rendering**

Extensions use JS, and ***have*** to modify the DOM

Now, I know that Extensions can modify the DOM, and to get what I wanted I could get something like:

```
<p>Extensions use JS, and <html:span style="font-weight: bold; font-style: italic;">have</html:span> to modify the DOM</p>
```

So, what I'm trying to do is NOT change the markup, at all.  This would be something like the "Highlight all" functionality that you get when you're doing a "Find" on a page.

## Current Solution

I found an extension which fits as a viable solution to my problem:
[It's All Text!](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/its-all-text/contribute/roadblock/?src=dp-btn-primary&version=1.6.4)

While I would still like to have native browser highlighting, without modifying the markup, this will do fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an extension which fits as a viable solution to my problem:
[It's All Text!](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/its-all-text/contribute/roadblock/?src=dp-btn-primary&version=1.6.4)

While I would still like to have native browser highlighting, without modifying the markup, this will do fine.

This pulls it out of the page, into an editor, and syncs them up.  Works beautifully.

Answer (score 0):

You could inject CSS to make existing markup behave differently (e.g., `p { font-weight:bold; }` to bold all `<p>` elements, or `.foo { background-color: green }` to alter all elements with a `foo` class, etc.), but there is almost certainly no extension-level way to accomplish what you want. You'll have to modify the markup of the page if you want to modify arbitrary text on the page.

The only way to do what you want is to hack some low-level code and actually rewrite parts of WebKit and Gecko so that HTML is rendered differently than it should be.

Comment: Okay.  That's what I was curious about.  I know that the "Highlight all" option on Firefox doesn't change the mark up.  So maybe I'll download the source and see how they did that.  But as far as modifying the CSS for marking up existing elements.. I don't think that would work, unless I could match specific text within the text input, and modify _only_ that.

Comment: I'm curious as to why you don't want to add markup. Are you concerned about DOM-traversing scripts on the page that might mess up if you add additional nodes? Or something else?

Comment: And yes, you're correct that injecting only CSS is a weak solution that won't get you the fine degree of control you want.

Comment: Well, I'm working in an environment where I don't want to change the value of the input box, but I want to be able to style what is in there.